# Error Getting Dependencies for Matplotlib

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib, vagrant, virtualenv

I am trying to install the python package matplotlib from source. I cannot install the package from the repository using `sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib` because I need to be able to install the package in a `virtualenv` using a `requirmenets.txt` file. When I follow the [instructions](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/installing.html) to install dependencies I get the following error:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Picking 'matplotlib' as source package instead of 'python-matplotlib'
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-all-dbg : Depends: libpython3-all-dbg (= 3.4.0-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python3-dbg (= 3.4.0-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python3.4-dbg but it is not going to be installed
 python3-all-dev : Depends: libpython3-all-dev (= 3.4.0-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python3-dev (= 3.4.0-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python3.4-dev but it is not going to be installed
 python3-numpy-dbg : Depends: python3-dbg but it is not going to be installed
E: Build-dependencies for python-matplotlib could not be satisfied.
```

How do I fix the problem? I have already run `sudo apt-get update` and
`sudo apt-get upgrade` to no avail. Could I just directly install the dependencies listed in the error message (I thought that was the point of the command)? I am not even using Python 3 so not concerned about having the packages installed (though not sure why I need them either). When I try running `pip install -r requirements.txt` in the virtual environment I still get an error on installing matplotlib.

Comment: What happens when you run: sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib

Comment: The package installs globally as you would expect. But I need to install in the virtualenv, which requires that I be able to compile.

Comment: Well you might try this: sudo apt-get install -f . It was said to solve the problem of missing dependencies here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/563178/the-following-packages-have-unmet-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Generally you get this message when you're missing some repository - you could check the list of your active repo from `/etc/apt/sources.list`. In your case you might miss the `-src`repo

What is strange is that `python3-dev` is from main repo so it should be activated by default.

You can add repo by editing the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and add the following lines

```
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
```

You can get more info about the available repo from [this link](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Trusty_Packages_and_Repositories)

make sure to (re)run `sudo apt-get update` after you've done this change and you should be ok to install your dependencies

Comment: Error: 'deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted' invalid

Comment: yep I thought it could be added with `apt-add-repository` but you should rather edit the sources.list file